# regex with sed shell script

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I have a problem when I'm trying to regex a line in a document with sed.
Here is what I want to regex:

> proxy_pass http:\\193.168.19.35/;

I want to obtain the following result:

> proxy_pass http:\\193.168.19.32/;

This is what I have tried:

```
sed -r 's/^proxy_pass htpp\:\/\/[[:digit:]]+.*\/;/proxy_pass htpp\:\/\/192.168.81.29\/;/' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf > /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.temp
```

Can you guys help me here?

Comment: misspelling? `htpp` -> `http`?

Comment: No matter how many times you replace something with `192.168.81.29`, it will never end up with the result `193.168.19.32`... Making your question consistent would probably be a good idea...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed/29626460#29626460

Answer (score 2):

If you have a URL with `\\`, you need to add support for this pattern in your regex. I believe you just misspelt some words in your question.

So, if you want to match `proxy_pass http:\\193.168.19.32/;`, use

```
sed -r 's/^proxy_pass http\:\\\\[[:digit:]]+(\.[[:digit:]]+)*\/;/proxy_pass htpp\:\/\/192.168.81.29\/;/' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf > /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.temp
                            ^^^^            |---------------|
```

If you want to replace `proxy_pass http://193.168.19.32/;`, use

```
sed -r 's/^proxy_pass http\:\/\/[[:digit:]]+(\.[[:digit:]]+)*\/;/proxy_pass htpp\:\/\/192.168.81.29\/;/' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf > /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.temp
                            ^  ^            |---------------|
```

Pay attention to `(\.[[:digit:]]+)*` in the pattern, it makes it possible to match all the 4 parts of the IP address.